# Exception when trying to write a file to HDFS from Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, apache-spark-mllib

When trying to write to HDFS from Spark within Zeppelin, I am receiving this `ClassNotFoundException` for `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter`:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2106)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getOutputCommitter(JobConf.java:725)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:983)
```

Code that is trying to run:

```
val model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(someRDD, numIterations)
val modelPath = "hdfs:///some_path/LinearRegressionWithSGD"
model.save(sc, modelPath)
```

When searching for this class, I cannot even find it.  The closest I can find is [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputCommitter in Hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileOutputCommitter.html).

I am using commit `18c8c9ea512a0d87699a73e2ca26192d03748661` (Oct 9) of [Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/), Spark 1.5.0 on YARN, and Hadoop 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Looked for that file in "hadoop-mapreduce-client-core.X.X.X.jar", but couldn't find that in the jar.

I fixed the problem by adding `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter` to my repository. Source of that file is found here : https://gist.github.com/apivovarov

Not sure yet what's the root cause of this issue. Digging into it. Will update here once I have the answer.